# Could player discard nearest cards to place the part of `War Machine` in proper order?

Tags: chaos-marauders

Suppose, player got a part of `War Machine` after attack. Could he discard nearest cards to place the machine in proper order, even if he have another rooms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No. You may only discard other cards if there are not enough open spaces.** From the Fantasy Flight [Chaos Marauders - Card Reference](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/chaos-marauders/PDF/chaos-marauders-card-ref-en.pdf) (page 14), regarding taking War Machine parts:

> ... He must then place the cards in his own battle lines - If there are not enough open spaces, he must discard cards to make room.